# Is it possible to join a MS-SQL to MySQL in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

I apologize if this is a silly question. This is probably well out of standard practice, but I'm looking to be able to join data from a MS-SQL database with that of MySQL in Laravel 5.2.

I'm not sure if it's possible to do something like...

```
\DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('mstable')
   ->leftJoin(\DB::connection('mysql')->table('mysqltable'), 
              'mysqltable.shared_id', 
              '=', 
              'mstable.shared_id');
```

My thinking is that if Laravel is converting the query early enough into a PHP object, it should be able to. Otherwise, is there a fallback to being able to use the two database types together?

Comment: No, it is not. You could however try to do this in MS-SQL itself by creating a linked database. Performance and functionality will be limited

Comment: No, you can't join across different database servers like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that a join won't be possible. What you can do though, is using relations on different databases. Depending on your situation this might be an applicable workaround. I am currently using this approach to query entities from different databases and "chunk" them so that I only keep  a couple of thousand entities in the memory. It's still an efficient way to iterate over all entities, because I'm using eager loading, so that Laravel / Eloquent only triggers two requests per chunk: One to get the primary models and the second to get the relation (by default this is done by an `IN` statement on the relation's table using the keys obtained from the primary models table).

A "simple" way to set this up is to fill the protected $connection property of the Eloquent Models like this:

```
class Foo extends Model{

  protected $connection = "mysql";

  public function bar(){
    return $this->hasOne(Bar::class);
  } 
}

class Bar extends Model{

  protected $connection = "ms-sql";
}

Foo::with("bar")->get();
```